Connect to disregarded host through VPN
I'm looking for some help, I'm trying to connect to a host under a 4G router through VPN.
First step, I'm using a raspberry pi 5 with raspberry pi os 64 bits, with openvpn3 installed on it. On a Synology NAS I have activated the OpenVPN server and opened the firewall ports to work with it.
Everything is working, from any computer I can connect with OpenVPN Connect to the VPN and the raspberry is also connected to the VPN server, so I can reach the raspberry.
IP Configuration:

Raspberry: local IP 192.168.5.100, VPN IP 10.8.0.5
PC: local IP 192.168.1.105, VPN IP 10.8.0.6

Now the problem: in the same net as the raspberry, I have a device (192.168.5.14) accessible via http, and I want to reach it from the pc connected to the vpn.
I have investigated how could I configure the raspberry to create any static route, or create some type of redirection to a "imaginary ip", for example 10.8.0.20, that points to the device. Also I configure to point raspberry 80 port to device's 80 port.
Someone can help me to configure this?
Thanks in advance

Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

@guiverc ty for advise, didn't notice

You've tagged the question as for a Debian-Ubuntu workflow issue related to Debian sid and Ubuntu development, but your question doesn't seem to approach that (or even mention packaging as per your Debian workflow tag)   This is a Ubuntu site; where much development of Ubuntu is combined with Debian, but focus here is the Ubuntu side of that process, given this is an official Ubuntu Q&A/Support site (accessible via your Ubuntu SSO or via Stack Exchange too)
